# Delete a column at particular index in a List of List using Java 8

Tags: java-8

I have a List of List of elements(`datalst`) and I want to delete some index elements in it as per another List(`removeIndex` ),How can I do it in `Java8`. Please help

```
private static List<List> removeUnwantedRecords(List<List> datalst, List<Integer> removeIndex ){
         datalst.forEach( row-> {
            for(int counter = 0 ; counter< removeIndex.size();counter++) {
                 List<Object> evenIndexedNames1 = IntStream
                          .range(0, row.size())
                          .filter(i -> i != 4 )
                          .mapToObj(i -> row.get(i))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());

                 evenIndexedNames1.forEach(str-> System.out.print(str));
            }
     });
    datalst.forEach(str-> System.out.println(str));
    return datalst;
}
```

This works fine but instead of 4,I would like to iterate a List(`removeIndex`),Can you please suggest any other approach in `Java8`

Comment: This is valid Java 8 code. Mission accomplished

Comment: @Michael , How it is done?? user is asking `This works fine but instead of 4...he wants...` .

Comment: I would like to iterate or loop through a removeIndex List and remove all the elements at that index from the datalst.

Comment: `dataList.forEach(list -> removeIndex.forEach(list::remove));`

Comment: Replace `i != 4` with `!removeIndex.contains(i)`.

Comment: @HadiJ that’s quiet dangerous. I don’t know whether this will invoke `remove(Object) ` or `remove(int)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas :

- favor generic to raw types ( `List<List<?>>` rather than  `List<List>`)
- don't collect if you want to change the state of the input lists
  But removing an element at a specified index changes the index (index=index-1) of all elements after it. To avoid that caveat you could process the list that contains indexes to remove in a descending order.
- `List.remove(int)` is a straight way to remove an element by index but we cannot pass any int value in. Indeed passing a int parameter out of bounds of the list throws an exception. So it has to be considered.

You could write something like :

```
  private static List<List<?>> removeUnwantedRecords(List<List<?>> datalst, List<Integer> removeIndex) {
    removeIndex.stream()
               .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
               .mapToInt(i -> i)
               .forEach(i -> datalst.stream()
                                    .filter(l -> i < l.size())
                                    .forEach(l -> l.remove(i)));
    return datalst;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is not safe to remove list elements by index through looping.

```
dataList.forEach(list -> list.removeAll(removeIndex
            .stream()
            .filter(i -> i < list.size())
            .map(list::get).collect(Collectors.toList()))
);
```

in fact, when you are removing the element from the list elements' index is modifying and it works just for the first index and other indexes are not correct.